# Request Catalog Form

Tags: magento-1.9

**I would like to ask on how to create a request catalog form in Magento 1.9.1.0.**

I want to create a Request Catalog Form using the contact form.

Or do I need to create my own module on it.

Comment: You can create a new module for that. You can use the contact us also but it is easy to create a new module for that.

Comment: I would suggest you create a custom module for it and leave Magento's default functionality untouched.

Comment: Thank you. Can you guide me please?

Answer (score 2):

**You should create Own custom module**

**or try   below free extension**

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fme-quick-rfq-request-for-quote.html

Comment: I want to create a custom module, can you please assist me.